# I want to url redired in asp.net using web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have one or more than one url like http://vfiresolution.in/pdf/p.pdf. And I want to redirect the above url to http://vfiresolution.in/page.aspx?id=1.
I am using the below given code. My code is working on local host. But If i publish my code on shared server code not working.

my code is

```
<configuration>
  <location path="pdf/p.pdf">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://vfiresolution.in/page.aspx?id=1" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>  
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

check the **iis** 
(httpredirect)

Compatibility
The httpRedirect section of web.config is compatible with IIS 7 (w2k8) and IIS 7.5 (w2k8 r2).

Web.config files are deeply integrated with IIS 7.x.

The httpRedirect directives listed will apply to all files and directories (php, jpg, png, htm, etc), not just asp.net files.

While some web.config sections sometimes require that the containing directory is set as an application, this isn't one of them.
A simple web.config with a httpRedirect section may be placed in any directory, and the directory does NOT need to be set as an application.